# Sk-learn GridSearchCV fits on full data

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, topic-modeling, grid-search

I used sklearn GridSearchCV to search # of topics using lda model. After fitting the model, the fitted model is saved in CV_model.best_estimator_. Based on skelarn document, GridSearchCV has default option 'refit, default=True', which 'Refit an estimator using the best found parameters on the whole dataset.' [Sklearn GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)

Since the document says the it has already fit on the full data, I therefore believed 'CV_model.best_estimator_.fit_transform(full_train_data)' shall bring the same result as 'CV_model.best_estimator_.transform(full_train_data)' . However, outputs from using fit_transform and transform differ. What did I miss? Should I use fit_transform or transform after GridsearchCV?

Answer (score 0):

I realized it might be due to the unfixed random state, after I assigned a fixed random state, .transform() and .fit_transform() return same results.